# Using method from ContentPage after it is created as a NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble accessing a method from my ContentPage.
I have a mainPage in which I create a NavigationPage with a ContentPage as a Parameter. The ContentPage just holds a WebView. (BrowserPage is the ContentPage)

```
public static NavigationPage browserPage;  
browserPage = new NavigationPage(new BrowserPage());
```

How can I access properties and methods from the ContentPage?

```
browserPage.someMethodFromBrowserPage(someParameter);
```

I know that this wont work, I can only call methods from NavigationPage that way.

```
((BrowserPage)browserPage).someMethod(someParameter);
```

This is also not working, its says NavigationPage cannot be converted to BrowserPage.

So, how do I cast accordingly so I can use the methods that I created inside the BrowserPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NavigationPage and the BrowserPage it contains are two independent things.  You can easily keep a ref to both:

```
public static BrowserPage browserPage = new BrowserPage();
var navPage = new NavigationPage(browserPage);
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the way i ended up doing it, just thought there could be a way without a reference.